# Scala Spark : How to extract nested column names from parquet file and adding prefix to it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

The idea is to read a parquet file into dataFrame. Then, extract all column name's and type's from it's schema. If we have a nested columns, i would like to add a "prefix" before the column name.

Considering that we can have a nested column with sub column named properly, and we can have also a nested column with just an array of array without column name but "element".

```
val dfSource: DataFrame = spark.read.parquet("path.parquet")
val dfSourceSchema: StructType = dfSource.schema
```

**Example of dfSourceSchema (Input):**

```
 |-- exCar: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- exProduct: string (nullable = true)
 |-- exName: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- exNameOne: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- exNameTwo: string (nullable = true)
```

**Desired output :**

```
((exCar.prefix.prefix,binary)),(exProduct, String), (exName.prefix.exNameOne, String), (exName.prefix.exNameTwo, String) )
```

Comment: add sample from your `parquet` file to read into a dataframe and generate the required results

Comment: @Vaebhav i have created a dataframe with the same structure. 
It's empty but the structure is the same.

FYI: 
`val schema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("exCar",ArrayType(ArrayType(BinaryType,true),true),true),
        StructField("exProduct", StringType),        
        StructField("exName", ArrayType(new StructType().add("exNameOne",StringType).add("exNameTwo",StringType), true))))
val data = Seq( Row(Array(Array((null))),"exProduct",null))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),  StructType(schema))`